# как поставить back button без header в react native

Tags: react-native, header, backbutton

Как в react native в stack navigator оставить back button без header-а?

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
    <Stack.Screen
        name="Event"
        component={EventScreen}
        options={{

        }}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо в `EventScreen` добавить эту кнопку, и использовать `navigation.goBack()`.

Если это много где надо, сделать можно обертку и передавать в `component`, к примеру:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Event"
        component={customBackButton(EventScreen)}
        options={{

        }}
    />
```